# What should I do to make MySQL transactions work in my code?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My queries are working no matter if all queries from transaction weren't successfully executed.

```
$this->mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

$query = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string("INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, `price`) VALUES (?,?)");
            $prod = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
            $prod->bind_param("ss", $name,$price);
            $prod->execute();

$query = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string("INSERT INTO `member` (`user`, `address`) VALUES (?,?)");
            $prod = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
            $prod->bind_param("ss", $user,$address);
            $prod->execute();

$query = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string(" SOME BAD WRITTEN QUERY") ;
            $prod = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
            $prod->execute();


if (!$this->mysqli->commit())
{
    print("\nTransaction commit failed\n");
    $this->mysqli->rollback();
}
$this->mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);
```

This code is working and inserting first two queries, of course breaks on third.

But transaction isn't working, no matter what it will insert every query that works, and I want to insert only if all three queries are done properly.

I use INNODB engine and PHP 5.5

Comment: did you begin a transaction?  `mysqli->begin_transaction()`

Comment: @gloomy.penguin When autocommit is off, you don't need to explicitly begin transactions, only commit them.

Comment: You should _not_ be calling `real_escape_string()` on the SQL statements. You are binding parameters correctly, and that is sufficient. There is no benefit, and potentially some harm to attempting to escape the entire SQL statement. Just use `$query = "INSERT INTO...VALUES (?,?)"` to build plain strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the transaction has been implicitly started since `autocommit` was disabled, MySQL is *not* internally tracking the success state of the statements you execute. That is *your* job as the programmer.  So even if `SOME BAD WRITTEN QUERY` fails, the previous two succeeded and can be committed.

You must test for the success of each and `commit()` or `rollback()` accordingly:

Note: You should *not* call `real_escape_string()` on the SQL statements. It is potentially harmful, and definitely not necessary for the prepared statement string.

```
$this->mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

$query = "INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, `price`) VALUES (?,?)";
$prod = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
$prod->bind_param("ss", $name,$price);

// Store success/fail in a variable (returns TRUE on success)
$success1 = $prod->execute();

$query = "INSERT INTO `member` (`user`, `address`) VALUES (?,?)";
$prod = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
$prod->bind_param("ss", $user,$address);

// Store success/fail in a variable (returns TRUE on success)
$success2 = $prod->execute();

$query = " SOME BAD WRITTEN QUERY";
$prod = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);

// Store success/fail in a variable (returns FALSE on failure)
$success3 = $prod->execute();

// Now check if all 3 succeeded and commit() if they did
if ($success1 && $success2 && $success3)
{
  $this->mysqli->commit();
}
// Or rollback() if they didn't
else
{
    print("\nTransaction commit failed\n");
    $this->mysqli->rollback();
}
$this->mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);
```

A final note. If you are only disabling `autocommit` for a single transaction then re-enabling it, consider just leaving `autocommit` *enabled* and explicitly beginning and ending the transaction.  Instead of calling `$this->mysqli->autocommit(false)` and later `$this->mysqli->autocommit(true);`, just call

```
// Don't disable autocommit
// Start it...
$this->mysqli->begin_transaction();
// Do your 3 queries as above and test for success
// Then commit or rollback
$this->mysqli->commit();
// (or rollback)
// Now, no need to re-enable auto-commit
```

If your application will use lots of transactions, then by all means disable `autocommit`. You'll need to explicitly `commit()` after every action, but I wouldn't disable it just to reenable it after one transaction.

And a note about DDL statements - MySQL cannot rollback DDL statements, and I believe calling one mid-transaction will cause all the previous statements to be committed, even though you have not yet explicitly called `commit()`. So beware of this if you are issuing `CREATE,ALTER,DROP` statements from your code. They cannot be used with transactions.

Answer (score 0):

as @gloomy.penguin says, you need to `mysqli->begin_transaction()` before you send the first transaction and then `mysqli->commit()` at the end.

disabling autocommit and then enabling autocommit is unnecessary unless of course you have more code that commits later.

Comment: Usually you don't need to do that. That's the point of disabling auto-commit. It implicitly starts a transaction until `commit()` is called.

Comment: ar ok... but its a bit long winded because you then have to implicitly enable autocommit.